# Linq Display Sort lidt

Tags: html, linq, listview

I have a Vehicle model with

- VehicleID
- VehicleName

List in the database

- Audi
- Hyndai
- Toyota
- Marcedes
- Other
- Accura
- Subaru
- Honda

I have used something like this in the past. to sort the order of the list to represent in the view.

@{var veh = (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Vehicles; veh = veh.OrderByDescending(v => v.Name != "Other").ThenBy(v => v.Name);}

Now i want to display the results in the below order.

- Audi
- Hyndai
- Marcedes
- Toyota
- Accura
- Subaru
- Honda
- Other

Orderby the list before "Other" following up with left list in sorted alphabetical order. At last with "other"

I wish i can explain much better. Any help is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **before** and **after** "Other"? Based on what - `VehicleID` or ?

Comment: based on the VehicleName

Comment: I don't understand. Based on `VehicleName`, how do you know which one is **before** and which one **after** "Other"? Look at your list in the database. Since it's not ordered by name, then how it is ordered? There must be some other property or something.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you.  :)

Comment: Lol, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@{var veh = (IEnumerable<Vehicle>)ViewBag.Vehicles; veh = veh.OrderByDescending(v => v.Name != "Other").ThenBy(v => Convert.ToInt32(v.IsActive)==0).ThenBy(v=>v.Name);}
@foreach (Vehicle v in veh)
{
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="VehicleId" value="@v.VehicleId" id="@v.VehicleId" />
    <span for="@v.VehicleId">@v.Name</span><br />
</div>

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This cheats a bit by using a external variable in the query, but it works..

```
var cars = new string[] {"Audi", "Hyndai", "Toyota", "Marcedes",
                         "Other", "Accura", "Subaru", "Honda"};

int seen = 0;
var list =  from car in cars
            let order = (car=="Other") ? seen=2 : (seen==2 ? 1 : 0)
            orderby order, car
            select car;

list.Dump();
```